# Graph API v2.2 : Sharing a friend's post on my wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a program that extracts the wall post all of my friends .

language use is -> php

I would like to share a post from a friend of mine ...

- My friend after public
- The app sees it and share it on my wall saying that I shared

I did not find anything about it so I'm just thinking that you can not do

Thanks for Everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Grap API v2.2 only allows to access your friedns feed who uses your application. If user is not one of  your app users, You can't access it's feed.

Comment: it's wrong... api graph permit a access to wall of post .. in the wall of post contain the notice of post to my friend... istruction is -> me/home ... extract post of wall ... the post is friend,page and other

Comment: Does this still work? I just started working with Graph v2.2 and I noticed that all posts in /me/home are posts by pages, and none are posts by users.

Comment: in the me/home compair post of user and page ... i personaly verified